# "Linking" Armatures together

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I have created kind of a.. Robot in blender, a legged boat, complete with bones and all.

I have also created, in the same project a character, rigged and ready to go.
In my animation I would like for the character to stand on the boat. Is there a way for me to attach the character armature to the root bone of the boat and still have the character armature fully functional within itself?

Sorry for bad phrasing. I am having a hard time explaining my issuse.

Comment: you could give your robot armature a Child Of constraint and choose the root bone as parent, don't forget to click the constraint Set Inverse button so that the armature stays where it was

Comment: Yeah, thanks! It worked out great, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You could give your robot armature a *Child Of* constraint and choose the root bone as parent, don't forget to click the constraint *Set Inverse* button so that the armature stays where it was.